# Android : Start a transition after another one ends

Tags: java, android, android-studio, animation, transition

I have a transition applied to several buttons where I try to change their width from 0dp to `MATCH_PARENT`

```
final ChangeBounds transition = new ChangeBounds();
startFloat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        for(i=0;i<allCards.size();i++) {
            if(i%2 == 0) {
                transition.setDuration(4000L);
                TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(allCards.get(i), transition);
                allButton.get(i).setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, dp10));
            }
            else{
                transition.setDuration(400L);
                TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(allCards.get(i), transition);
                allButton.get(i).setLayoutParams(new MaterialCardView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, dp10));
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Note: dp10 is an integer variable (No problem there).

This seems to work fine, however, when I click `startFloat` button, all the transitions occur at the same time. **I want them to start after the previous one ends**.

Any idea of how to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced the same problem few days ago. The solution is , you need to use different transitions for different views. You need to create two transitions here and use each of them once only. Try this

```
final ChangeBounds firestTransition = new ChangeBounds();
final ChangeBounds secondTransition= new ChangeBounds();

startFloat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        for(i=0;i<allCards.size();i++) {
            if(i%2 == 0) {
                firestTransition.setDuration(4000L);
                TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(allCards.get(i), transition);
                allButton.get(i).setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, dp10));
            }
            else{
                secondTransition.setDuration(400L);
                TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(allCards.get(i), transition);
                allButton.get(i).setLayoutParams(new MaterialCardView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, dp10));
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This only created two transitions, but they start at the same time. I want the second one to start only after first transition is complete

Answer (score 1):

You should use `TransitionSet` instead so you can configure that order as sequential. More details [here](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions#Multiple) and [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/TransitionSet) in the official Android docs

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem by using `transition.setStartDelay(delay)`.

Here is my code:

```
final ChangeBounds transition = new ChangeBounds();
startFloat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        for(int i=0;i<allCards.size();i++) {
            if(i%2 == 0) {
                transition.setDuration(4000L);
                transition.setStartDelay(delay);
                TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(allCards.get(i), transition);
                allButton.get(i).setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, dp10));
                delay+=4000;
            }
            else{
                transition.setDuration(400L);
                transition.setStartDelay(delay);
                TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(allCards.get(i), transition);
                allButton.get(i).setLayoutParams(new MaterialCardView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, dp10));
                delay+=400;
            }
        }
    }
});
```